# Detaching/opening an iframe into a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe setup within a page and basically want to know whether it's possible to have a button in this iframe and when pressed, opens the iframe into a new browser window, showing the contents of the iframe.

I am planning on using either JavaScript or jQuery to achieve this. I am using IE6.

Comment: Gah! IE6! You are doomed to failure! Just kidding...but really? IE6?

Comment: I guess if you can get it working in IE6 then you can do anything. Like catching fly with chopstick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.button').click( function(){
    window.open($('iframe').attr('src'),'mywindow','width=400,height=200');
});
```

Comment: but you may need to use more specific selector for iframe like its id `$("#frame1")`

Comment: Thanks for the replies - just one question though, I am using IE6 and I actually want the window.open() to open fullscreen with top toolbar so that user can close screen. I have tried the fullscreen but I can't get the top toolbar activated - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For what you need (to open the same page where this button), no matter if it's an iframe or if in the home page.

The only difference is if you want that data to open in new window, are a reflection of the same page, such as data that can be an input.

If you care about who are the same data:

```
$("#mybuttonOpenWin").click(function(){
   window.open(window.location.href);
});
```

If you are interested, you can try this code:

```
$("#mybuttonOpenWin").click(function(){
   var mref = window.open(window.location.href);

   (function = onReadyRef(xref){
      if(xref.window.document.readyState=="complete"){
        $(xref.window.document).find("body").html($("body").html());
      }
      else{
         onReadyRef.call(this, xref);
      }
   })(mref);
});
```